# MappedSuperclass Alternatives in Grails

Tags: grails, jpa, auditing

In many past projects, I used [this](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2008/08/using_a_hibernate_interceptor_to_set_audit_trail_properties.html) JPA / Hibernate approach to add auditing capabilities to a system. It's very effective and unobtrusive.

Is there a Grails @MappedSuperclass alternative (short of coding domain model objects in Java instead of Groovy)? How can one declare a parent class in a table-per-subclass approach without having a table created for it? I've read the GORM documentation ([5.2.3 Inheritance in GORM](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/1.2.1/guide/single.html#5.2.3%20Inheritance%20in%20GORM)) but besides the table-per-hierarchy vs. table-per-subclass discussion, I did not find any details on how to do this.

Alternatively, what is the recommended way to achieve this type of auditing in Grails?

Comment: Yes for some reason this does work in Grails 2 anymore the Abstract class gets there own table definition? Have asked on the Grails forum but nobody seems to know why this has been changed.
Anybody know why or know a workaround or setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, it's as simple as declaring the `MappedSuperclass` as `abstract` and Grails will not create a table for it. I realized by [re-reading the manual](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/1.2.1/guide/single.html#5.2.3%20Inheritance%20in%20GORM):

> GORM supports inheritance both from abstract base classes and concrete persistent GORM entities. I.e. concrete classes are persistent, so abstract ones are not. Pays to read more carefully.

E.g.

```
abstract class Auditable {
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
}

class Book extends Auditable {
    String title
    String description
}
```

Only the book table will be created and it will have the **`date_created`** and **`last_updated`** columns. Furthermore, as an added bonus, the `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` properties are [auto time-stamped](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/1.2.1/guide/single.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) by Grails.

Comment: @HussainFakhruddin you mean 2.x right? We are using 2.5.4